# Cut String at Special Position VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I got this string here: \server\Documents\test\\954076 
how i check if there is a \ a second time and how i cut it then off?
So that \server\Documents\test\\954076 is gonna be \server\Documents\test\954076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general solution to reduce any consecutive repetitions of a given character:

```
Sub RemoveRepetitions(s As String, c As String)
    Dim len1 As Long, len2 As Long
    Do
        len1 = Len(s)
        s = Replace(s, c & c, c)
        len2 = Len(s)
    Loop Until len2 = len1
End Sub

Sub testing()
    Dim s As String: s = "\\server\\\\\\Documents\\\\\test\\954076"
    RemoveRepetitions s, "\"
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

> \server\Documents\test\954076

Answer (score 1):

if you're worried about *double* repetitions then it suffices

```
Dim strng As String

strng = "\server\Documents\test\\\954076"

strng = Replace(strng, "\\", "\")
```

if you want to handle `multiple` repetitions then:

```
Dim strng As String

strng = "\server\Documents\test\\\954076"

Do While Len(strng) - Len(Replace(strng, "\\", "\")) > 0
    strng = Replace(strng, "\\", "\")
Loop
```